# how to submit form to different functions based on a condition jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form when submitted goes through validation and a function is called when it passes the validation check. Now what i want to do is depending on the value of a variable the form must be submitted to different functions.

```
$('#select_port').on('submit',function(e){
var port = $("input[name='port_type']:checked").val();

   if(port == "chennai" || "mumbai" || "calicut"){
    newport();
   }

   else if(port == 'gujarat' ){
    gujaratport();
   }
}
```

Only `newport()` is called no matter what the port value is. I want to call the `newport()` function if the port value is chennai, mumbai or calicut. If the port value is gujarat, then `gujaratport()` should be called. Now whatever the value is `newport()` function is called.

Comment: Can you update your question to add the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Your first condition :

```
if(port == "chennai" || "mumbai" || "calicut"){
   newport();
}
```

always evaluate to true because in javascript if (`a_non_empty_string`) evaluates to true. 

You should have used :

```
if(port == "chennai" || port == "mumbai" || port == "calicut"){
   newport();
}
```

`UPDATE`
Or for more flexibility, use a regular expression :

```
if (port.match(/^chennai|mumbai|calicut$/){
   newport();
}
```

Here you can see different ways to compare a string to multiple values :
https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/03/14/better-ways-of-comparing-a-javascript-string-to-multiple-values/

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking what the value of port is when it's saved, also ask yourself why you need an else if state to check for the gujarat case. If/Else is used in cases where it's one thing or it HAS to be another. If it isn't one of the three ports (chennai/mumbai/calicut), then you shouldn't need to check with an if again.